# Stop page loading from cache when internet is available

Tags: html, caching, offline, offline-caching

My project requires a offline feature. I've implemented the offline feature of HTML5 and it works fine. The issue I'm facing is that when the internet is available. The browser loads the data from the cache instead of getting the data from web server. I know it's because the manifest file has not changed.

Is there a way where I can force the browser to load data from server when internet is available and to load data from the cache when no internet is available?

My project is in CakePHP.

Answer (score 0):

I have a nice reading for [you](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp)

But Just to give you a preview you should create a *manifest file* and select which files/folders will be loaded with and without internet connection.

Example of a manifest code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="demo.appcache">
...
</html>
```

**The manifest** file is a simple text file, which tells the browser what to cache (and what to never cache).

The manifest file has three sections:

**CACHE MANIFEST** - Files listed under this header will be cached after they are downloaded for the first time

**NETWORK** - Files listed under this header require a connection to the server, and will never be cached

**FALLBACK** - Files listed under this header specifies fallback pages if a page is inaccessible

**Complete example**:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2016-08-29 v1.0.0
/theme.css
/logo.gif
/main.js

NETWORK:
login.asp

FALLBACK:
/html/ /offline.html
```

I hope this enlighten your thoughts my friend. =)

Comment: Yuri thanks for your comment. I'm aware of what you've commented. My project is in CakePHP. I've mentioned the assets in the Manifest file but Since cakePHP a simple Manifest file doesn't solve the issue what I'm facing.